# custom admin menu with custom filed

Tags: admin-menu

i am not so expert on WordPress yet.

I want to create custom admin menu section for my project.

For example see the attached image marked red area, there i want to add one section name **Project** under there two sub-menu. like *All Project*, and *ADD NEW*

Now whenever go to **all project** page it will show all project list same like all post, whenever go to **ADD NEW** it will have **Title, Description, Date (Date Picture), Attached File (file), Project Type (radio group).** filed.

[image]

Can anyone suggestion me how can do that. i know i have to do something on `function.php` page.

Answer (score 1):

there are many free portfolio plugin avaliable, simply install and activates that makes your work too easy: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/wordpress-portfolio-plugin/

Comment: thanks @loving nagi .. actually nothing about portfolio plugins issue. i need custom thing. if there have any plugins which is allow to create custom menu and post then i can use. i got custom admin plugins but not custom post type

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is a custom post type rather than adding a menu item. You can use the [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) action hook to register your own post type. To create a basic post type, simply use this piece of code in your plugin or theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Projects'
    );
    register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type' );
```

More advanced examples are provided in the above link. However, adding a menu item is done by using [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), as follows:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_menu_item' );
function register_my_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page( 
        'Page Title', 
        'Menu title', 
        'manage_options', // Capability
        'custom.php',     // Menu slug
        '',               // Callback function to output content
        'dashicons-icon', // Menu's icon 
        90                // Menu's position, 20 will work for you
    );
}
```

But this is not enough. You have to fill it with content too.

Comment: thank you so much. i will try tomorrow. how can i make custom page input filed item ?

Comment: You're welcome. [Here](https://paulund.co.uk/theme-options-page) is a step by step guide for what you are looking into.